# Cassandra config change to use hostnames after ip's changed

Tags: cassandra

Initial installation of Cassandra was done using IP addresses and it has been working for 6+ months.  This past weekend DevOps changed security to not allow IP addresses and also reassigned new IP addresses.  I modified the required files (cassandra.yaml, cassandra-rackdc.properties, etc) to contain hostnames.  The issue is nodetool status gives the error, Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199, and I do have JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=blah" in cassandra-env.sh. Any ideas how to proceed to the environment back up?  Should I go through the same files and replace hostnames with the new IP addresses?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Try `nodetool -h your_new_host status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options to provide listen address in Cassandra.yaml.

- listen_address
- listen_interface

To be completely agnostic of the IP address or hostname, use the option of listen_interface and comment the listen_address. Here is the Cassandra.yaml change required

```
# Address or interface to bind to and tell other Cassandra nodes to  connect to.
#
#listen_address: xx.xxx.xx.xxx

# Set listen_address OR listen_interface, not both. Interfaces must    correspond
# to a single address, IP aliasing is not supported.
listen_interface: eth0
```

To figure out the actual listen_interface, issue the command

- **ifconfig -a**
- Pick the interface that shows, "UP BROADCAST RUNNING". (eth0 in mycase)

The output should look like

```
root@ip-xx-xxx-x-xxx:~# ifconfig -a
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
      inet addr:xxx.xx.x.x  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:152 (152.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
         inet addr:xx.xxx.xx.xx  Bcast:xx.xxx.xx.xx  Mask:255.255.0.0
         UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
         RX packets:169552382 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:185182015 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:88406501352 (88.4 GB)  TX bytes:126516101404 (126.5 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:xx.xxx.xx.xx  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:38490371 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38490371 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:41155731774 (41.1 GB)  TX bytes:41155731774 (41.1 GB)
```

Restart Cassandra and you should be good to go. **Another advantage is that Cassandra.yaml no longer has to be different across your nodes** (assuming all have the same network interface).

Comment: Very helpful.  Regards.